# How do I access the recycle bin of my old (corrupt) profile?

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7.

So last week my usual profile went corrupt and I had to create a new user profile and copy my important files over to my new profile.

Only problem is, just before my old profile corrupted I had a very important Excel file on my desktop.

I usually use my desktop as a temporary space to put files and images and clear it from time to time. As the law of the world inevitably goes, I wiped my desktop files a day before my profile went corrupt and put them all in the Recycle Bin. I did not empty the Recycle Bin.

I can't find the important Excel file anywhere, no matter what I do, and would place a heavy bet that it's in that recycle bin by mistake. I've tried everything- I've unchecked all hidden files and folders, I've tried 'runas' in CMD, and I really really need that file. It's pretty frustrating that as the profile is corrupt I can no longer just log in as myself and take a look.

Any help would be great, especially in layman's terms if poss.

Comment: Access is denied to all the folders- annoying as this is my laptop and I'm the only admin! :/

Answer (score 1):

There is only one main recycle bin folder, `\$Recycle.Bin\`, with each user having a folder labeled by SID within it.

See [Recycle bin forensics in windows 7 and visa](http://dereknewton.com/2010/06/recycle-bin-forensics-in-windows-7-and-vista/) for an overview of how to recover these files.

The process involves looking through files with names like `$I<random characters>` at bytes 24-543 for the original file name you want to recover, and then renaming/moving the corresponding `$R<same random characters>` file.

If you have access to a linux install or live cd, there is a reasonable procedure to recover the file from Linux that may also be helpful over at [processing vista recyclebin](http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.com/2009/10/processing-vista-recyclebin.html)

Comment: I've finally found the file! I am ecstatic... almost. As you said, it has a different name, lots of numbers in, and it won't open in Excel because the file name is incorrect.

I've checked out your link but still not entirely sure what to do. Sorry- I'm not techy, just a normal person- any way you can explain how I can get it to open?

Comment: You should just be able to rename the $R<random characters>.xls (or xlsx) to tempname.xls (or xlsx) and have it open normally. Is this not working for you? Are you sure the file wasn't corrupted along with your old profile? You don't say how that corruption occurred, but with something like an unsafe shutdown its possible to corrupt any file which had an open file handle.

Comment: @Sam, Hey, **did you manage to do it eventually?**

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, even if you were able to find the path your file was at i am almost positive you would be unable to recover it due to the corrupt profile, when you recycle something it saves an instance of the file for recovery, so if you have a wiped or corrupt profile, chances are that the instance was also deleted as well, have you tried a system restore to a previous date ? Seems simple but its worth mentioning.

Comment: I can access my other files in my corrupt profile without a problem, I just can't find where the Recycling Bin is and take a look through it (I didn't empty it, if that helps). I'd rather not System Restore but it's worth bearing in mind, thank you!